# Unity.RegistrationByConvention.WithXXX members are accessed like properties when they are actually methods

Tags: c#, .net, inversion-of-control, unity-container, ioc-container

In most examples [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/unity-part-6-registration-by-convention), [here](http://mylifeandcode.blogspot.ca/2014/04/register-types-by-convention-with-unity.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16299221/how-to-prevent-unity-overwriting-existing-mappings-with-autoregistration), I see that the methods on the classes `WithMappings`, `WithLifetime` and `WithName` from the assembly `Microsoft.Practices.Unity.RegistrationByConvention.dll` version 3.5.0 are accessed as though they were properties but when I look them up in Reflector, I see that they are methods and they expect (mostly) a `System.Type` or an array of `System.Type`.

What's the deal? Are those examples wrong or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the definition of the container.RegisterTypes method, you will see that getFromTypes, getName, getLifetimeManager, and getInjectionMembers are all expecting type Func, which means they expect a method. getName for example is defined as:

```
Func<Type, string> getName = null
```

This allows you to pass in a method that accepts a Type parameter and returns a string, such as the standard `string WithName.TypeName(Type type)` method. However, it also gives you the flexibility of defining your own method with the same signature if you want to provide custom registration naming logic to Unity, or example.